# Trigger - Add to a date using a subquery

Tags: postgresql-9.2, subquery, trigger

(postgresql 9.2)
I'v 2 tables

**Table 1 (extinguisher)**

```
extinguisher_id (serial)
type_designation_extinguisher_type(text)
manufacturing_date (date)
life_date(date)
```

**Table 2 (extinguisher_designation)**

```
extinguihser_type(serial)
extinguisher_designation(text)
lifespan(int)
```

lifespan can take values like: 10 or 20 and it represents years

My objective is to do a trigger that will automatically populate table1.life_date based on the extinguisher_type using table2.

The problem is that lifespan is an int and can change.
The usual way to add year to a date is using
date + interval '10 year'

The problem is that I want a variable instead of the 10.

At this point i'v this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ext_life_span()

RETURNS trigger AS

$BODY$

DECLARE
new_date timestamptz;
manu_date char(10);
intervalo char(10);
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
intervalo := to_char((SELECT lifespan FROM extinguisher_type, extinguisher where type_designation = type_designation_extinguisher_type), '99999');
manu_date := to_char(New.manufacturing_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
new_date := (date 'manu_date' + integer 'intervalo' );
update extinguisher set life_date = new_date;
RETURN NULL;
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
IF new.manufacturing_date IS DISTINCT FROM old.manufacturing_date THEN
intervalo := to_char((SELECT lifespan FROM extinguisher_type, extinguisher where type_designation = type_designation_extinguisher_type), '99999');
manu_date := to_char(New.manufacturing_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
new_date := (date 'manu_date' + integer 'intervalo' );
update extinguisher set life_date = new_date;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END IF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION ext_life_span() OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_lifespan
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF manufacturing_date
ON "extinguisher"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE ext_life_span();
```

I'm getting an error: invalid input syntax for type date: "menu_date"

Am I doing the best approach? Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use a variable when doing something like this:

```
menu_date := menu_date + interval '1' year * num_years
```

Where num_years holds the number of years that should be added.

You get the error because `date 'manu_date'` is an incorrect date literal because the string (!) `'manu_dat'` is not a valid date. The expression `date 'xxxx'` requires a date definition in ISO format e.g. `date '2013-09-27'`

Regarding your trigger:

The statement `update extinguisher set life_date = new_date;` will update ***all*** rows in the table `extinguisher`. I'm pretty sure that is *not* what you want. You are missing a `where` condition for the update.

You also cannot run an `update` on the table on which the trigger is fired. You simply assign the value to the `new` record.

I although I absolutely don't understand what you intend with your trigger, I *think* what you want is much simpler:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ext_life_span()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    l_lifespan integer; 
BEGIN

  -- note that this can fail, if type_designation is not unique!!!
  SELECT lifespan 
    into l_lifespan
  FROM extinguisher_type
  WHERE type_designation = new.type_designation_extinguisher_type;

  new.life_date := new.manufacturing_date + interval '1' year * l_lifespan;

  RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

---

Edit: depending on your data volumn, you could also get rid of the trigger and the `life_date` column alltogether and simply calculate that value "on-the-fly" using a view:

```
select ex.extinguisher_id, 
       ex.manufacturing_date,
       ex.manufacturing_date + interval '1' year * ed.life_span as life_date
from extinguisher ex
  join extinguisher_designation ed 
       -- I'm not sure I understand your data model correctly.
       -- you need to setup a proper FK here e.g. by using the generated ID
    on ed.extinguihser_type = ex.extinguihser_type
```

That way the value will *always* be up-to-date and you never need to worry about triggers.

In a relational database, values that can be derived from existing values should not be stored.

Comment: That works! Thank you! Now the problem is that the select statement is returning multiple rows :/

Comment: @Olhinho: I don't understand your table structure anyway. Why is `type_designation_extinguisher_type` a `text` column? Shouldn't that be an `integer` referencing the "serial" column of the `extinguisher_designation` table? (assuming that is the primary key of that table)

Comment: That's the name pgmodeler gave to the FK i cant change that. Well i can, once it is on postgres but i didnt yet...

Comment: But those are *column* names, not foreign key names.

Comment: It is supposed to be a integer as FK from the serial in table2, but for now i'm using type_designation as FK bc it's easier for me to build examples, type_designation is unique anyway. Later on it is easy to change that back. Or, since type_designation is unique i should eliminate type_id?  I will post the solution i used in some hours... can't post it yet, new user :D. Thank you very much for answering it so fast.